# Is there a way to define a protocol class in Android?

Tags: android, ios

I am new to Android and was working on iOS for the longest time imaginable. Just have a basic question regarding the protocol class. Here is my protocol class in iOS:

```
#import "ServiceBaseProtocol.h"
#import "ServiceTasksProtocol.h"

@protocol AnswersServiceProtocol <ServiceBaseProtocol>
- (NSUInteger)answersQueryIntentForTarget:(id<ServiceTaskCallbackProtocol>)target requestInput:(NSString*)requestInput;
@end
```

Is it possible to convert this into equivalent android code. How do I go about the same?

Comment: You might consider explaining what this is, since not every Android developer is an iOS developer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(Java)

Comment: Protocol is not a class, by the way. Protocol defines an interface. And how do you define an interface in java? Using an `abstract` class or using `interface` keyword. Note the two languages are pretty different, you can't directly translate everything from one language to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protocols are called interfaces in Java. So your piece of code might look like:

```
 public interface AnswersServiceProtocol extends ServiceBaseProtocol
 {
    public int answersQueryIntentForTargetAndRequestInput(ServiceTaskCallbackProtocol target, String requestInput);
 }
```